# Cannot save filtered image to external storage android

Tags: java, android

I am not a Java guy at all.
While using `react-native-vision-camera`, I need to create my own frame processor. This frame processor will simply apply some opengl filter on each frame and return the path where the filtered image is saved. This is what I have written so far, most of them is copied from here and there to fit my need.

```
package com.story;

import android.util.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.System;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy;
import android.media.Image;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import org.wysaid.common.Common;
import org.wysaid.common.SharedContext;
import org.wysaid.myUtils.FileUtil;
import org.wysaid.myUtils.ImageUtil;
import org.wysaid.myUtils.MsgUtil;
import org.wysaid.nativePort.CGEImageHandler;
import org.wysaid.nativePort.CGENativeLibrary;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeMap;
import com.mrousavy.camera.frameprocessor.FrameProcessorPlugin;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class FrameEffectPlugin extends FrameProcessorPlugin {

    public static String status = "";

    private Bitmap convertImageProxyToBitmap(ImageProxy image) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length,null);
    }

    public String saveBitmap(Bitmap finalBitmap, String fname) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/cache-images");
        if(!myDir.exists() || !myDir.isDirectory()){
            myDir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete ();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = "exception while saving bitmap";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    @Override
    public Object callback(@NotNull ImageProxy image, Object[] params) {
        Bitmap bitmapImg = convertImageProxyToBitmap(image);
        String ruleString = "@adjust hsl 0.02 -0.31 -0.17";

        Bitmap dstImage = CGENativeLibrary.filterImage_MultipleEffects(bitmapImg, ruleString, 1.0f);
        String timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
        String fname = "storyCache_"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
        String path = saveBitmap(dstImage, fname);

        WritableNativeMap map = new WritableNativeMap();
        map.putString("path", path);
        map.putString("status", status);
        return map;
    }

    FrameEffectPlugin() {
        super("addFrameEffect");
    }
}
```

It always says `exception while saving bitmap` as status. If I try to render the image in react native with the path returned, it doesn't show anything(which should actually happen).

At this point, I think the problem is happening from `convertImageProxyToBitmap()` function. It is being unable to produce a Bitmap so the library(gpuimage-plus) is unable to apply filters. So, the image is not being saved.

But I am a noob in this field so I don't have any idea what to fix/to do next. Please help me to solve this :(

Comment: You did not even tell the path where your image should be saved but failed.

Comment: Further you should mention Android version of used device.

Comment: Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet. And if you call it then check the return value and stop if it is false. Display only a toast to inform the user then. Please adapt your code. Also here. And report.

Comment: @blackapps I used android 11. But I did declare the path in `FIle file = new File(myDir, fname);`

Comment: `It always says exception while saving bitmap as status.` That is your own message. You should change it to `status = "exception while saving bitmap: " + e.getMessage();` Further you shoud return null if you have an exception there and not a path as you do now. But.. you will not have an exception there if you follow my suggestions for mkdir.

Comment: `Cannot save filtered image to external storage android` You should change that to: `Cannot create directory 'cache-images' on external storage.`.

Comment: I am building with your suggested fix, let me check what it says

Comment: @blackapps execption returned: `"exception while saving bitmap: /storage/emulated/0/cache-images/storyCache_1635694870504.jpg (No such file or directory)"`

Comment: You did not what i suggested. `if(!myDir.mkdirs()){Toast( .... cannot create directory...); return;}`

Comment: I cant show toasts that way, because It's being called from react native.

Comment: Well then log or whatever. And return. You cannot create that directory is what i said. Why did you still not confirm? Why dont you realise?

Comment: I did edit my code(check my updated code that I edited before commenting here) and checked if the dir doesn't exist, if not, then create dir

Comment: My god... That dir is not created and you dont know. Add code: `if(!myDir.mkdir()) return;`

Comment: oh well, i am editing my code and compiling. let me check